# Ignore all dir's but one

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to ignore all directories within a directory except one. Here is my file hierarchy.

```
project
  .gitignore
  main.rb
  libs
    foo
      foo.rb
    bar
      bar.rb
    com
      com.rb
```

I want to ignore all directories in libs except com
Here is what i tried in .gitignore

```
/libs/ 
!/libs/com/
```

When I do `git status` libs dir is not listed

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you ignore libs, libs/com is never found.
Instead ignore everything in libs, except com.

```
/libs/*
!/libs/com/
```